# How to call an assembly procedure from c++ code

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I'd like to call from my `c++` code some 3-rd party text outputting procedure which i have an memory offset. Here is the `assembly` code of the function:

```
op_float_msg_ proc near                      ; initIntExtra_+628o

a3         = dword ptr -3Ch
_object    = dword ptr -34h
a2         = byte ptr -30h
font       = dword ptr -28h
outline_clr= dword ptr -24h
clr        = dword ptr -20h
text       = dword ptr -1Ch

           push    ebx
           push    ecx
           push    edx
           push    esi
           push    edi
           push    ebp
           sub     esp, 34h
           mov     ecx, eax
           mov     ebx, 65h
           xor     eax, eax
           xor     edx, edx
           xor     edi, edi
           xor     esi, esi
           mov     al, ds:_YellowColor
           xor     ebp, ebp
           mov     [esp+4Ch+clr], eax
           xor     eax, eax
           mov     [esp+4Ch+text], edx
           mov     al, ds:_colorTable        ; Ś˝ÓşŰę
           mov     [esp+4Ch+font], ebx
           mov     [esp+4Ch+outline_clr], eax

loc_4592B6:                                  ; op_float_msg_+BEj
           mov     eax, ecx                  ; a1
           call    interpretPopShort_        ; Get value type
           mov     word ptr [esp+esi+4Ch+a2], ax
           mov     eax, ecx                  ; a1
           call    interpretPopLong_         ; Get value
           mov     dx, word ptr [esp+esi+4Ch+a2]
           mov     [esp+ebp+4Ch+a3], eax
           cmp     dx, 9801h
           jnz     short loc_4592E9
           mov     ebx, eax                  ; a3
           xor     edx, edx
           mov     eax, ecx                  ; result
           mov     dx, word ptr [esp+esi+4Ch+a2] ; a2
           call    interpretDecStringRef_

loc_4592E9:                                  ; op_float_msg_+57j
           cmp     edi, 1
           jz      short loc_459312
           xor     eax, eax
           mov     ax, word ptr [esp+esi+4Ch+a2]
           and     ah, 0F7h
           cmp     eax, 0C001h
           jz      short loc_459334
           push    edi
           mov     eax, [ecx]
           push    eax
           push    offset asc_50683C         ; "script error: %s: invalid arg %d to flo"...
           call    interpretError_
           add     esp, 0Ch
           jmp     short loc_459334
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

loc_459312:                                  ; op_float_msg_+6Cj
           xor     edx, edx
           mov     dx, word ptr [esp+esi+4Ch+a2] ; a2
           mov     eax, edx
           and     ah, 0F7h
           cmp     eax, 9001h
           jnz     short loc_459334
           mov     eax, ecx                  ; a1
           mov     ebx, [esp+ebp+4Ch+a3]     ; a3
           call    interpretGetString_
           mov     [esp+4Ch+text], eax

loc_459334:                                  ; op_float_msg_+7Dj ...
           add     ebp, 4
           inc     edi
           add     esi, 2
           cmp     edi, 3
           jl      loc_4592B6
           mov     edx, [esp+4Ch+_object]
           test    edx, edx
           jnz     short loc_459362
           mov     ebx, 1                    ; type
           mov     edx, offset aFloat_msg    ; "float_msg"
           mov     eax, ecx                  ; arg
           call    dbg_error_
           jmp     loc_459496
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

loc_459362:                                  ; op_float_msg_+CAj
           mov     ebx, [esp+4Ch+text]
           mov     esi, edx
           test    ebx, ebx
           jz      short loc_459371
           cmp     byte ptr [ebx], 0
           jnz     short loc_459387

loc_459371:                                  ; op_float_msg_+EAj
           mov     eax, esi                  ; result
           call    text_object_remove_
           call    tile_refresh_display_
           add     esp, 34h
           pop     ebp
           pop     edi
           pop     esi
           pop     edx
           pop     ecx
           pop     ebx
           retn
```

Based on the code above how can I call pass the parameters to the function, especially the string to display? I know, that it's maybe a little guessing but can someone please help me try to deduce it?

Comment: Seems to be taking input via `eax` which is a non-standard way. Also it may not be a pointer to char.

Comment: @Jester Yes, but how could it be if the `eax` is `xor`'ed so all the value stored here is erased?

Comment: @Daros911: It's `mov`ed to `ecx` first.

Comment: @Jester Yes, You're right. So may I try to move the string offset/address to the `eax` register and then call the function?

Comment: Worth a try, but note it's passed to various `interpret*` functions including a final `interpretGetString` which is a strong hint that this is not just a string.